# Does anyone know a way to do median inside HQL?

Tags: sql-server, hql, median

Does anyone know a way to do median inside HQL?

I'm using SQL Server(an older version so I can't use PERCENTILE_CONT) and most of the ways I've found require over, which I can't figure out how to do in hql. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do hql median quickly or at all?